# Functionally changing key names in serialization to aeson with Text keys

Tags: json, haskell, text, aeson

I have a json object with a manually crafted ToJSON instance.  I would like to  replace this with a function that does not require my explicit enumeration of the key names.

I am using "rec*" as a prefix I would like to strip, and my fields start out as Text rather than string.

Starting with minimal data:

```
data R3 = R3 { recCode :: Code 
             , recValue :: Value} deriving (Show, Generic)
```

And smart constructor function:

```
makeR3 rawcode rawval = R3 code value where
                                     code = rawcode
                                     value = rawval
```

This implementation works fine:

```
instance ToJSON R3 where
   toJSON (R3 recCode recValue) = object [ "code" .= recCode, "value" .= recValue]
```

But as you can imagine, typing out every key name by hand from "code" to "recCode" is not something I want to do.

```
tmp_r3 = makeR3 "TD" "100.42"
as_json = encode tmp_r3

main = do
    let out = encodeToLazyText tmp_r3
    I.putStrLn out
    I.writeFile "./so.json" out
    return ()
```

Output is correct:

```
{"value":100.42,"code":"TD"}
-- not recValue and recCode, correct!
```

However, when I try this function, it becomes unable to convert the text to string as it had automatically before.

```
instance ToJSON R3 where
  toJSON = genericToJSON defaultOptions {
             fieldLabelModifier = T.toLower . IHaskellPrelude.drop 3 }
```

Output:

```
<interactive>:8:35: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Text’ with ‘String’
      Expected type: String -> String
        Actual type: String -> Text
    • In the ‘fieldLabelModifier’ field of a record
      In the first argument of ‘genericToJSON’, namely ‘defaultOptions {fieldLabelModifier = toLower . IHaskellPrelude.drop 3}’
      In the expression: genericToJSON defaultOptions {fieldLabelModifier = toLower . IHaskellPrelude.drop 3}
<interactive>:8:47: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘String’ with ‘Text’
      Expected type: String -> Text
        Actual type: String -> String
    • In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘IHaskellPrelude.drop 3’
      In the ‘fieldLabelModifier’ field of a record
      In the first argument of ‘genericToJSON’, namely ‘defaultOptions {fieldLabelModifier = toLower . IHaskellPrelude.drop 3}’
```

The error itself is clear enough that Text doesn't work, but what should I change to strip my prefixes from keynames functionally in json output 
and also correctly convert text to string?

I am also a little confused that I didn't change my input, it was Text type in both instances, but the first implementation was OK to work with it, while the second was not.

I am working in an ihaskell jupyter notebook.

### Update

When I use the Data.Char recommended in answers below:

```
import Data.Char(toLower)
```

In:

```
instance ToJSON R3 where
  toJSON = genericToJSON defaultOptions {
             fieldLabelModifier = Data.Char.toLower . IHaskellPrelude.drop 3 }
```

I get:

```
<interactive>:8:35: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Char’ with ‘String’
      Expected type: String -> String
        Actual type: String -> Char
    • In the ‘fieldLabelModifier’ field of a record
      In the first argument of ‘genericToJSON’, namely ‘defaultOptions {fieldLabelModifier = Data.Char.toLower . IHaskellPrelude.drop 3}’
      In the expression: genericToJSON defaultOptions {fieldLabelModifier = Data.Char.toLower . IHaskellPrelude.drop 3}
<interactive>:8:55: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘String’ with ‘Char’
      Expected type: String -> Char
        Actual type: String -> String
    • In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘IHaskellPrelude.drop 3’
      In the ‘fieldLabelModifier’ field of a record
      In the first argument of ‘genericToJSON’, namely ‘defaultOptions {fieldLabelModifier = Data.Char.toLower . IHaskellPrelude.drop 3}’
```

And when I try a naked "drop" rather than an IHaskellPrelude drop, I get:

```
instance ToJSON R3 where
  toJSON = genericToJSON defaultOptions {
             fieldLabelModifier = Data.Char.toLower . drop 3 }

<interactive>:8:55: error:
    Ambiguous occurrence ‘drop’
    It could refer to either ‘BS.drop’, imported from ‘Data.ByteString’
                          or ‘IHaskellPrelude.drop’, imported from ‘Prelude’ (and originally defined in ‘GHC.List’)
                          or ‘T.drop’, imported from ‘Data.Text’
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You compose two function `T.toLower` and `drop 3`, but the types do not match. Indeed, if we lookup the types, we see [**`toLower :: Text -> Text`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.3.1/docs/Data-Text.html#v:toLower) and [**`drop :: Int -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:drop). A `String` is a list of `Char`s, but `Text` is not: a `Text` can be seen as a packed "block" of characters.

We can however compose a function of type `String -> String`, the type of the field [`fieldLabelModifier :: String -> String`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.4.2.0/docs/src/Data.Aeson.Types.Internal.html#fieldLabelModifier):

```
import Data.Char(toLower)

instance ToJSON R3 where
    toJSON = genericToJSON defaultOptions {
            fieldLabelModifier = map toLower . drop 3
        }
```

We thus use the [**`toLower :: Char -> Char`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:toLower) function of the `Data.Char` module, and perform a `map`ping, such that all characters in the string are mapped.

Note that if you simply want to derive `FromJson` and `ToJSON` with different options, you can make use of *template Haskell*, like:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric, TemplateHaskell #-}

import Data.Char(toUpper)
import Data.Aeson.TH(deriveJSON, defaultOptions, Options(fieldLabelModifier))

data Test = Test { attribute :: String } deriving Show

$(deriveJSON defaultOptions {fieldLabelModifier = map toUpper . drop 3} ''Test)
```

In that case the template Haskell part will implement the `FromJSON` and `ToJSON` instances.

> **Note**: We can use qualified imports in order to make it more clear what function we use, for example:
>
> ```
> import qualified Data.List as L
> import qualified Data.Char as C
>
> instance ToJSON R3 where
>     toJSON = genericToJSON defaultOptions {
>             fieldLabelModifier = map C.toLower . L.drop 3
>         }
> ```

> **Note**: As for the smart constructor, you can simplify this expression to:
>
> ```
> makeR3 = R3
> ```

Comment: Thank you.  This gives me `<interactive>:8:35: error:
    Ambiguous occurrence ‘toLower’`  What is the customary alias given to the import of Data.Char?  I have Prelude, Data.Text, Data.ByteString as BS, Data.Text.Lazy.IO as I. Half a dozen other string conversions.  I am still learning, but I have yet to find a problem that hasn't required me to import and juggle every string library possible, unfortunately.

Comment: @Mittenchops: you can just hide the `toLower` of your `Text`, for example with `import Data.Text hiding (toLower)`.

Comment: But that would prevent me from using it, right? I am using it in other places of my program.

Comment: @Mittenchops: well you can define two import statements: `import Data.Text hiding (toLower)` and `import qualified Data.Text as T` for example. Or just import the `Data.Char` in a qualified way.

Comment: Thank you.  This is very helpful.  I'm confused by this `Note: As for the smart constructor, you can simplify this expression to:

    makeR3 = R3` My understanding was that making functions that create data types was preferable to just using the naked data type itself.  Is that not the case?

Comment: @Mittenchops: a smart constructor is typically used to (a) prevent exporting the data constructor, and thus preventing a user of the module to *unpack* a constructor, which here is still done, and (b) to do pre-processing an validation, but here you did not write any pre-processing or validation logic. Hence we can define the `makeR3` function as `makeR3 = R3`. But we can not use this function to *unpack* data.

Comment: Thank you!  This is helpful!

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be using `toLower` from `Data.Text`, which works with `Text`, not with `String`, so quite naturally, it doesn't fit there.

Instead, you could use [`toLower` from `Data.Char`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-13.18/base-4.12.0.0/Data-Char.html#v:toLower) and `map` it over the `String`:

```
fieldLabelModifier = map toLower . drop 3
```

Comment: This seems to conflict with the Data.Text I am importing.

Comment: So import it as qualified then?