# Where is IHaskellPrelude coming from in this error?

Tags: haskell, jupyter, ihaskell, haskell-prelude

I'm working in an ihaskell jupyter notebook, so I know the obvious answer to this.

But I'm also using an explicit import from Data.List where it shows this error

```
import qualified Data.List as L
```

So I am actually confused about the line that quotes IHaskellPrelude is involved instead
of my explicit import from Data.List which is not prelude.  (This is a more specific question following from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55818022/functionally-changing-key-names-in-serialization-to-aeson-with-text-keys))

My error message:

```
<interactive>:14:35: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Char’ with ‘String’
      Expected type: String -> String
        Actual type: String -> Char
    • In the ‘fieldLabelModifier’ field of a record
      In the first argument of ‘genericToJSON’, namely ‘defaultOptions {fieldLabelModifier = Data.Char.toLower . IHaskellPrelude.drop 3}’
      In the expression: genericToJSON defaultOptions {fieldLabelModifier = Data.Char.toLower . IHaskellPrelude.drop 3}
<interactive>:14:47: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘String’ with ‘Char’
      Expected type: String -> Char
        Actual type: String -> String
    • In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘IHaskellPrelude.drop 3’
      In the ‘fieldLabelModifier’ field of a record
      In the first argument of ‘genericToJSON’, namely ‘defaultOptions {fieldLabelModifier = Data.Char.toLower . IHaskellPrelude.drop 3}’
```

See the line about the fieldLabelModifier?  It calls IHaskellPrelude.drop.  But if you look below, my code calls L.drop:

Full code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric,  OverloadedStrings, RankNTypes, KindSignatures #-}
:ext DeriveGeneric OverloadedStrings FlexibleContexts RankNTypes KindSignatures DataKinds

-- stack overflow question
import GHC.Generics
import Data.Aeson 
import Data.Aeson.Encode.Pretty 
import Data.Time
-- every dumb library working with any text in haskell requires
import Data.Text as T
import Text.Show.Pretty
import Data.Char(toLower)
import qualified Data.List as L
import qualified Data.Char as C
import Data.ByteString as BS
import Data.Aeson.Text (encodeToLazyText)
import Data.Text.Lazy.IO as I
--
import Text.Regex.PCRE
(.=) = (Data.Aeson..=)

type Code = Text
type Value = Float

-- currency parser
-- Sample
currency = "100.01"

-- -- Value part
vparse :: T.Text -> Float
vparse raw = (read ((T.unpack raw) =~ ("[\\d].*") :: String) :: Float)


data R3 = R3 { recCode :: Code 
             , recValue :: Value} deriving (Show, Generic)


makeR3 rawcode rawval = R3 code value where
                                     code = rawcode
                                     value = vparse rawval


instance ToJSON R3 where
  toJSON = genericToJSON defaultOptions {
             fieldLabelModifier = C.toLower . L.drop 3 }
-- this says L.drop not prelude!  


instance FromJSON R3 where
  parseJSON = withObject "R3" $ \r ->
      R3 <$> r .: "code"
         <*> r .: "value"

r3 = makeR3 "TD" "100.42"
as_json = encode r3


main = do
    let out = encodeToLazyText r3
    I.putStrLn out
    I.writeFile "./so2.json" out
    return ()

main
```

I am working in a new session, new terminal, have only run this.  I don't understand why the error message quoted to me is using a function sourced from IHaskellPrelude.drop rather than the L.drop I am explicitly calling.

### Update

From suggestion in answer, when I try:

```
instance ToJSON R3 where
  toJSON = genericToJSON defaultOptions {
             fieldLabelModifier = map toLower . L.drop 3 }
```

I get:

```
<interactive>:14:35: error:
    Ambiguous occurrence ‘map’
    It could refer to either ‘BS.map’, imported from ‘Data.ByteString’
                          or ‘T.map’, imported from ‘Data.Text’
                          or ‘IHaskellPrelude.map’, imported from ‘Prelude’ (and originally defined in ‘GHC.Base’)
<interactive>:14:39: error:
    Ambiguous occurrence ‘toLower’
    It could refer to either ‘Data.Char.toLower’, imported from ‘Data.Char’ at <interactive>:1:18-24 (and originally defined in ‘GHC.Unicode’)
                          or ‘T.toLower’, imported from ‘Data.Text’
```

Which combination of these is compatible with what Prelude is asking for?

Comment: Answer for update: ``instance ToJSON R3 where
  toJSON = genericToJSON defaultOptions {
             fieldLabelModifier = IHaskellPrelude.map C.toLower . L.drop 3 }
``

Comment: Or also ``instance ToJSON R3 where
  toJSON = genericToJSON defaultOptions {
             fieldLabelModifier = L.map C.toLower . L.drop 3 }
``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter if it's `IHaskellPrelude.drop` or `Data.List.drop`: they're *the same thing*. Both the standard Prelude and the IHaskell one simply re-exports the list `drop` function. GHC notices that, and thus apparently decides to inform you about the more “basic” import-path, i.e. the one from the prelude. (I don't know how the heuristic works, but usually GHC is quite good at showing the most convenient import qualifier-name for a binding.)

The problem is that your `toJSON` is just not type correct, because `toLower` only works on a `Char`, not on a `String`. This can easily be solved by using `map toLower`.

Comment: Ahhhh. I didn't realize that was where Prelude got it.  Interesting.